# How to address the attachment field in a Microsoft Access form using VBA?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, attachment

I build a form where users can create a new record and fill the fields. One of those fields is the attachment field. Before they can save the record, I want to check wether they filled in all mandatory fields, the attachment beeing one of those. With all other fields, it works like this:

```
        If IsNull(date_of_useage) Then
            MsgBox "Please fill in the date!", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

This does not work für the attachment field, addressing it by its name "attachment". How can I check, if the user did or did not attach a file? `IsEmpty` didnt work either.

Answer (score 0):

Found a Solution:

```
If Attachment.Attachmentcount = 0 Then [...]
```